# Web/search engine spider on local network?

Tags: network, firewalls, ip

I was setting up a test webserver on my local network earlier, and whilst sorting out the firewall I noticed the following in the log (`/var/log/ufw.log` - I'm using UFW on Ubuntu 14.04):

```
Jul  9 14:17:46 wilf-G560 kernel: [ 7098.779915] [UFW BLOCK] IN=eth0 OUT= MAC=**:**:**:**:**:**:00:13:33:a7:c6:98:08:00 SRC=173.194.137.119 DST=192.168.1.27 LEN=1444 TOS=0x00 PREC=0x00 TTL=61 ID=23785 DF PROTO=TCP SPT=443 DPT=44814 WINDOW=371 RES=0x00 ACK URGP=0
```

Looking up the source IP 173.194.137.119 shows that is one of Google's servers, possibly acting as a search engine spider.

Should this IP be able to access the local network in this way? And what can be done to prevent it (if it needs preventing)?

**EDIT:** More have appeared:

```
Jul  9 14:07:46 wilf-G570 kernel: [ 7098.779915] [UFW BLOCK] IN=eth0 OUT= MAC=20:89:84:3b:68:fc:00:13:33:a7:c6:98:08:00 SRC=173.194.137.119 DST=192.168.1.27 LEN=1444 TOS=0x00 PREC=0x00 TTL=61 ID=23785 DF PROTO=TCP SPT=443 DPT=44814 WINDOW=371 RES=0x00 ACK URGP=0 
Jul  9 14:07:50 wilf-G570 kernel: [ 7102.688464] [UFW BLOCK] IN=eth0 OUT= MAC=20:89:84:3b:68:fc:00:13:33:a7:c6:98:08:00 SRC=173.194.137.119 DST=192.168.1.27 LEN=1444 TOS=0x00 PREC=0x00 TTL=61 ID=23786 DF PROTO=TCP SPT=443 DPT=44814 WINDOW=371 RES=0x00 ACK URGP=0 
Jul  9 18:38:00 wilf-G570 kernel: [23331.391334] [UFW BLOCK] IN=eth0 OUT= MAC=20:89:84:3b:68:fc:00:13:33:a7:c6:98:08:00 SRC=190.93.246.58 DST=192.168.1.27 LEN=40 TOS=0x00 PREC=0x00 TTL=61 ID=55845 DF PROTO=TCP SPT=80 DPT=60500 WINDOW=31 RES=0x00 ACK FIN URGP=0 
Jul  9 18:38:01 wilf-G570 kernel: [23331.761791] [UFW BLOCK] IN=eth0 OUT= MAC=20:89:84:3b:68:fc:00:13:33:a7:c6:98:08:00 SRC=190.93.246.58 DST=192.168.1.27 LEN=40 TOS=0x00 PREC=0x00 TTL=61 ID=49408 DF PROTO=TCP SPT=80 DPT=60499 WINDOW=32 RES=0x00 ACK FIN URGP=0 
Jul  9 18:38:02 wilf-G570 kernel: [23333.404910] [UFW BLOCK] IN=eth0 OUT= MAC=20:89:84:3b:68:fc:00:13:33:a7:c6:98:08:00 SRC=104.16.19.44 DST=192.168.1.27 LEN=40 TOS=0x00 PREC=0x00 TTL=61 ID=46158 DF PROTO=TCP SPT=80 DPT=48452 WINDOW=38 RES=0x00 ACK FIN URGP=0 
Jul  9 18:38:02 wilf-G570 kernel: [23333.643089] [UFW BLOCK] IN=eth0 OUT= MAC=20:89:84:3b:68:fc:00:13:33:a7:c6:98:08:00 SRC=104.16.19.44 DST=192.168.1.27 LEN=40 TOS=0x00 PREC=0x00 TTL=61 ID=46159 DF PROTO=TCP SPT=80 DPT=48452 WINDOW=38 RES=0x00 ACK FIN URGP=0 
Jul  9 18:38:03 wilf-G570 kernel: [23333.933479] [UFW BLOCK] IN=eth0 OUT= MAC=20:89:84:3b:68:fc:00:13:33:a7:c6:98:08:00 SRC=104.16.19.44 DST=192.168.1.27 LEN=40 TOS=0x00 PREC=0x00 TTL=61 ID=46160 DF PROTO=TCP SPT=80 DPT=48452 WINDOW=38 RES=0x00 ACK FIN URGP=0 
Jul  9 18:38:03 wilf-G570 kernel: [23334.514076] [UFW BLOCK] IN=eth0 OUT= MAC=20:89:84:3b:68:fc:00:13:33:a7:c6:98:08:00 SRC=104.16.19.44 DST=192.168.1.27 LEN=40 TOS=0x00 PREC=0x00 TTL=61 ID=46161 DF PROTO=TCP SPT=80 DPT=48452 WINDOW=38 RES=0x00 ACK FIN URGP=0 
Jul  9 18:38:04 wilf-G570 kernel: [23335.085606] [UFW BLOCK] IN=eth0 OUT= MAC=20:89:84:3b:68:fc:00:13:33:a7:c6:98:08:00 SRC=190.93.246.58 DST=192.168.1.27 LEN=40 TOS=0x00 PREC=0x00 TTL=61 ID=55846 DF PROTO=TCP SPT=80 DPT=60500 WINDOW=31 RES=0x00 ACK FIN URGP=0 
Jul  9 18:38:04 wilf-G570 kernel: [23335.675592] [UFW BLOCK] IN=eth0 OUT= MAC=20:89:84:3b:68:fc:00:13:33:a7:c6:98:08:00 SRC=104.16.19.44 DST=192.168.1.27 LEN=40 TOS=0x00 PREC=0x00 TTL=61 ID=46162 DF PROTO=TCP SPT=80 DPT=48452 WINDOW=38 RES=0x00 ACK FIN URGP=0 
Jul  9 18:38:05 wilf-G570 kernel: [23335.776453] [UFW BLOCK] IN=eth0 OUT= MAC=20:89:84:3b:68:fc:00:13:33:a7:c6:98:08:00 SRC=190.93.246.58 DST=192.168.1.27 LEN=40 TOS=0x00 PREC=0x00 TTL=61 ID=49409 DF PROTO=TCP SPT=80 DPT=60499 WINDOW=32 RES=0x00 ACK FIN URGP=0 
Jul  9 18:38:07 wilf-G570 kernel: [23337.997768] [UFW BLOCK] IN=eth0 OUT= MAC=20:89:84:3b:68:fc:00:13:33:a7:c6:98:08:00 SRC=104.16.19.44 DST=192.168.1.27 LEN=40 TOS=0x00 PREC=0x00 TTL=61 ID=46163 DF PROTO=TCP SPT=80 DPT=48452 WINDOW=38 RES=0x00 ACK FIN URGP=0 
Jul  9 18:38:14 wilf-G570 kernel: [23345.535105] [UFW BLOCK] IN=eth0 OUT= MAC=20:89:84:3b:68:fc:00:13:33:a7:c6:98:08:00 SRC=54.230.196.88 DST=192.168.1.27 LEN=83 TOS=0x00 PREC=0x00 TTL=56 ID=7910 DF PROTO=TCP SPT=443 DPT=54089 WINDOW=76 RES=0x00 ACK PSH URGP=0 
Jul  9 18:38:14 wilf-G570 kernel: [23345.763121] [UFW BLOCK] IN=eth0 OUT= MAC=20:89:84:3b:68:fc:00:13:33:a7:c6:98:08:00 SRC=54.230.196.88 DST=192.168.1.27 LEN=83 TOS=0x00 PREC=0x00 TTL=56 ID=7912 DF PROTO=TCP SPT=443 DPT=54089 WINDOW=76 RES=0x00 ACK PSH URGP=0 
Jul  9 18:38:15 wilf-G570 kernel: [23346.223534] [UFW BLOCK] IN=eth0 OUT= MAC=20:89:84:3b:68:fc:00:13:33:a7:c6:98:08:00 SRC=54.230.196.88 DST=192.168.1.27 LEN=83 TOS=0x00 PREC=0x00 TTL=56 ID=7913 DF PROTO=TCP SPT=443 DPT=54089 WINDOW=76 RES=0x00 ACK PSH URGP=0 
Jul  9 18:38:16 wilf-G570 kernel: [23347.144806] [UFW BLOCK] IN=eth0 OUT= MAC=20:89:84:3b:68:fc:00:13:33:a7:c6:98:08:00 SRC=54.230.196.88 DST=192.168.1.27 LEN=83 TOS=0x00 PREC=0x00 TTL=56 ID=7914 DF PROTO=TCP SPT=443 DPT=54089 WINDOW=76 RES=0x00 ACK PSH URGP=0 
Jul  9 18:38:18 wilf-G570 kernel: [23348.986666] [UFW BLOCK] IN=eth0 OUT= MAC=20:89:84:3b:68:fc:00:13:33:a7:c6:98:08:00 SRC=54.230.196.88 DST=192.168.1.27 LEN=83 TOS=0x00 PREC=0x00 TTL=56 ID=7915 DF PROTO=TCP SPT=443 DPT=54089 WINDOW=76 RES=0x00 ACK PSH URGP=0 
Jul  9 18:38:21 wilf-G570 kernel: [23352.681009] [UFW BLOCK] IN=eth0 OUT= MAC=20:89:84:3b:68:fc:00:13:33:a7:c6:98:08:00 SRC=54.230.196.88 DST=192.168.1.27 LEN=83 TOS=0x00 PREC=0x00 TTL=56 ID=7916 DF PROTO=TCP SPT=443 DPT=54089 WINDOW=76 RES=0x00 ACK PSH URGP=0 
Jul  9 18:38:26 wilf-G570 kernel: [23357.391779] [UFW BLOCK] IN=eth0 OUT= MAC=20:89:84:3b:68:fc:00:13:33:a7:c6:98:08:00 SRC=190.93.246.58 DST=192.168.1.27 LEN=40 TOS=0x00 PREC=0x00 TTL=61 ID=55848 DF PROTO=TCP SPT=80 DPT=60500 WINDOW=31 RES=0x00 ACK FIN URGP=0 
Jul  9 18:38:29 wilf-G570 kernel: [23360.069087] [UFW BLOCK] IN=eth0 OUT= MAC=20:89:84:3b:68:fc:00:13:33:a7:c6:98:08:00 SRC=54.230.196.88 DST=192.168.1.27 LEN=83 TOS=0x00 PREC=0x00 TTL=56 ID=7917 DF PROTO=TCP SPT=443 DPT=54089 WINDOW=76 RES=0x00 ACK PSH URGP=0 
Jul  9 18:38:42 wilf-G570 kernel: [23373.010203] [UFW BLOCK] IN=eth0 OUT= MAC=20:89:84:3b:68:fc:00:13:33:a7:c6:98:08:00 SRC=216.58.208.69 DST=192.168.1.27 LEN=112 TOS=0x00 PREC=0x00 TTL=59 ID=20174 PROTO=TCP SPT=443 DPT=33267 WINDOW=350 RES=0x00 ACK PSH URGP=0 
Jul  9 18:38:42 wilf-G570 kernel: [23373.010312] [UFW BLOCK] IN=eth0 OUT= MAC=20:89:84:3b:68:fc:00:13:33:a7:c6:98:08:00 SRC=216.58.208.69 DST=192.168.1.27 LEN=52 TOS=0x00 PREC=0x00 TTL=59 ID=20175 PROTO=TCP SPT=443 DPT=33267 WINDOW=350 RES=0x00 ACK FIN URGP=0 
Jul  9 18:38:42 wilf-G570 kernel: [23373.309781] [UFW BLOCK] IN=eth0 OUT= MAC=20:89:84:3b:68:fc:00:13:33:a7:c6:98:08:00 SRC=216.58.208.69 DST=192.168.1.27 LEN=112 TOS=0x00 PREC=0x00 TTL=59 ID=20345 PROTO=TCP SPT=443 DPT=33267 WINDOW=350 RES=0x00 ACK PSH URGP=0 
Jul  9 18:38:42 wilf-G570 kernel: [23373.776558] [UFW BLOCK] IN=eth0 OUT= MAC=20:89:84:3b:68:fc:00:13:33:a7:c6:98:08:00 SRC=216.58.208.69 DST=192.168.1.27 LEN=112 TOS=0x00 PREC=0x00 TTL=59 ID=20578 PROTO=TCP SPT=443 DPT=33267 WINDOW=350 RES=0x00 ACK PSH URGP=0 
Jul  9 18:38:43 wilf-G570 kernel: [23374.709408] [UFW BLOCK] IN=eth0 OUT= MAC=20:89:84:3b:68:fc:00:13:33:a7:c6:98:08:00 SRC=216.58.208.69 DST=192.168.1.27 LEN=112 TOS=0x00 PREC=0x00 TTL=59 ID=21195 PROTO=TCP SPT=443 DPT=33267 WINDOW=350 RES=0x00 ACK PSH URGP=0 
Jul  9 18:39:13 wilf-G570 kernel: [23404.339884] [UFW BLOCK] IN=eth0 OUT= MAC=20:89:84:3b:68:fc:00:13:33:a7:c6:98:08:00 SRC=54.230.196.88 DST=192.168.1.27 LEN=83 TOS=0x00 PREC=0x00 TTL=56 ID=7919 DF PROTO=TCP SPT=443 DPT=54089 WINDOW=76 RES=0x00 ACK PSH URGP=0 
Jul  9 18:39:14 wilf-G570 kernel: [23404.849395] [UFW BLOCK] IN=eth0 OUT= MAC=20:89:84:3b:68:fc:00:13:33:a7:c6:98:08:00 SRC=68.232.34.191 DST=192.168.1.27 LEN=40 TOS=0x00 PREC=0x00 TTL=60 ID=22175 DF PROTO=TCP SPT=443 DPT=43857 WINDOW=35 RES=0x00 ACK FIN URGP=0 
Jul  9 18:39:21 wilf-G570 kernel: [23412.813543] [UFW BLOCK] IN=eth0 OUT= MAC=20:89:84:3b:68:fc:00:13:33:a7:c6:98:08:00 SRC=68.232.34.191 DST=192.168.1.27 LEN=40 TOS=0x00 PREC=0x00 TTL=60 ID=22180 DF PROTO=TCP SPT=443 DPT=43857 WINDOW=35 RES=0x00 ACK FIN URGP=0 
Jul  9 18:39:46 wilf-G570 kernel: [23437.860462] [UFW BLOCK] IN=eth0 OUT= MAC=20:89:84:3b:68:fc:00:13:33:a7:c6:98:08:00 SRC=68.232.35.121 DST=192.168.1.27 LEN=52 TOS=0x00 PREC=0x00 TTL=60 ID=8305 DF PROTO=TCP SPT=443 DPT=35983 WINDOW=33 RES=0x00 ACK FIN URGP=0 
Jul  9 18:40:03 wilf-G570 kernel: [23454.085469] [UFW BLOCK] IN=eth0 OUT= MAC=20:89:84:3b:68:fc:00:13:33:a7:c6:98:08:00 SRC=68.232.35.121 DST=192.168.1.27 LEN=52 TOS=0x00 PREC=0x00 TTL=61 ID=50379 DF PROTO=TCP SPT=443 DPT=35984 WINDOW=33 RES=0x00 ACK FIN URGP=0 
Jul  9 18:40:20 wilf-G570 kernel: [23471.594482] [UFW BLOCK] IN=eth0 OUT= MAC=20:89:84:3b:68:fc:00:13:33:a7:c6:98:08:00 SRC=68.232.35.121 DST=192.168.1.27 LEN=52 TOS=0x00 PREC=0x00 TTL=61 ID=63175 DF PROTO=TCP SPT=443 DPT=35993 WINDOW=35 RES=0x00 ACK FIN URGP=0 
Jul  9 18:40:42 wilf-G570 kernel: [23493.642084] [UFW BLOCK] IN=eth0 OUT= MAC=20:89:84:3b:68:fc:00:13:33:a7:c6:98:08:00 SRC=216.58.208.35 DST=192.168.1.27 LEN=52 TOS=0x00 PREC=0x00 TTL=58 ID=12818 PROTO=TCP SPT=80 DPT=44679 WINDOW=353 RES=0x00 ACK FIN URGP=0 
Jul  9 18:41:01 wilf-G570 kernel: [23512.000355] [UFW BLOCK] IN=eth0 OUT= MAC=20:89:84:3b:68:fc:00:13:33:a7:c6:98:08:00 SRC=68.232.35.121 DST=192.168.1.27 LEN=52 TOS=0x00 PREC=0x00 TTL=61 ID=3465 DF PROTO=TCP SPT=443 DPT=35989 WINDOW=39 RES=0x00 ACK FIN URGP=0 
Jul  9 18:41:25 wilf-G570 kernel: [23536.885696] [UFW BLOCK] IN=eth0 OUT= MAC=20:89:84:3b:68:fc:00:13:33:a7:c6:98:08:00 SRC=68.232.35.121 DST=192.168.1.27 LEN=52 TOS=0x00 PREC=0x00 TTL=60 ID=57524 DF PROTO=TCP SPT=443 DPT=35980 WINDOW=41 RES=0x00 ACK FIN URGP=0 
Jul  9 18:45:10 wilf-G570 kernel: [23762.184153] [UFW BLOCK] IN=eth0 OUT= MAC=20:89:84:3b:68:fc:00:13:33:a7:c6:98:08:00 SRC=37.220.108.145 DST=192.168.1.27 LEN=572 TOS=0x00 PREC=0x00 TTL=56 ID=43139 DF PROTO=TCP SPT=443 DPT=34710 WINDOW=40 RES=0x00 ACK PSH URGP=0 
Jul  9 18:46:15 wilf-G570 kernel: [23826.362521] [UFW BLOCK] IN=eth0 OUT= MAC=20:89:84:3b:68:fc:00:13:33:a7:c6:98:08:00 SRC=216.58.208.35 DST=192.168.1.27 LEN=52 TOS=0x00 PREC=0x00 TTL=58 ID=20928 PROTO=TCP SPT=80 DPT=44794 WINDOW=342 RES=0x00 ACK FIN URGP=0 
Jul  9 18:46:15 wilf-G570 kernel: [23826.514952] [UFW BLOCK] IN=eth0 OUT= MAC=20:89:84:3b:68:fc:00:13:33:a7:c6:98:08:00 SRC=216.58.208.78 DST=192.168.1.27 LEN=52 TOS=0x00 PREC=0x00 TTL=59 ID=11045 PROTO=TCP SPT=80 DPT=43774 WINDOW=342 RES=0x00 ACK FIN URGP=0 
Jul  9 18:46:15 wilf-G570 kernel: [23826.595365] [UFW BLOCK] IN=eth0 OUT= MAC=20:89:84:3b:68:fc:00:13:33:a7:c6:98:08:00 SRC=216.58.208.35 DST=192.168.1.27 LEN=52 TOS=0x00 PREC=0x00 TTL=58 ID=21041 PROTO=TCP SPT=80 DPT=44794 WINDOW=342 RES=0x00 ACK FIN URGP=0 
Jul  9 18:46:15 wilf-G570 kernel: [23826.829191] [UFW BLOCK] IN=eth0 OUT= MAC=20:89:84:3b:68:fc:00:13:33:a7:c6:98:08:00 SRC=216.58.208.35 DST=192.168.1.27 LEN=52 TOS=0x00 PREC=0x00 TTL=58 ID=21146 PROTO=TCP SPT=80 DPT=44794 WINDOW=342 RES=0x00 ACK FIN URGP=0 
Jul  9 18:46:15 wilf-G570 kernel: [23827.295850] [UFW BLOCK] IN=eth0 OUT= MAC=20:89:84:3b:68:fc:00:13:33:a7:c6:98:08:00 SRC=216.58.208.35 DST=192.168.1.27 LEN=52 TOS=0x00 PREC=0x00 TTL=58 ID=21425 PROTO=TCP SPT=80 DPT=44794 WINDOW=342 RES=0x00 ACK FIN URGP=0 
Jul  9 18:46:16 wilf-G570 kernel: [23828.228693] [UFW BLOCK] IN=eth0 OUT= MAC=20:89:84:3b:68:fc:00:13:33:a7:c6:98:08:00 SRC=216.58.208.35 DST=192.168.1.27 LEN=52 TOS=0x00 PREC=0x00 TTL=58 ID=22003 PROTO=TCP SPT=80 DPT=44794 WINDOW=342 RES=0x00 ACK FIN URGP=0 
Jul  9 18:46:18 wilf-G570 kernel: [23830.094832] [UFW BLOCK] IN=eth0 OUT= MAC=20:89:84:3b:68:fc:00:13:33:a7:c6:98:08:00 SRC=216.58.208.35 DST=192.168.1.27 LEN=52 TOS=0x00 PREC=0x00 TTL=58 ID=23250 PROTO=TCP SPT=80 DPT=44794 WINDOW=342 RES=0x00 ACK FIN URGP=0 
Jul  9 18:46:47 wilf-G570 kernel: [23858.365082] [UFW BLOCK] IN=eth0 OUT= MAC=20:89:84:3b:68:fc:00:13:33:a7:c6:98:08:00 SRC=23.67.255.201 DST=192.168.1.27 LEN=52 TOS=0x00 PREC=0x00 TTL=61 ID=32375 DF PROTO=TCP SPT=80 DPT=40661 WINDOW=587 RES=0x00 ACK FIN URGP=0 
Jul  9 18:46:47 wilf-G570 kernel: [23858.607436] [UFW BLOCK] IN=eth0 OUT= MAC=20:89:84:3b:68:fc:00:13:33:a7:c6:98:08:00 SRC=23.67.255.201 DST=192.168.1.27 LEN=52 TOS=0x00 PREC=0x00 TTL=61 ID=1873 DF PROTO=TCP SPT=80 DPT=40660 WINDOW=587 RES=0x00 ACK FIN URGP=0 
Jul  9 18:46:47 wilf-G570 kernel: [23858.610938] [UFW BLOCK] IN=eth0 OUT= MAC=20:89:84:3b:68:fc:00:13:33:a7:c6:98:08:00 SRC=23.67.255.201 DST=192.168.1.27 LEN=52 TOS=0x00 PREC=0x00 TTL=61 ID=32376 DF PROTO=TCP SPT=80 DPT=40661 WINDOW=587 RES=0x00 ACK FIN URGP=0 
Jul  9 18:46:47 wilf-G570 kernel: [23858.850655] [UFW BLOCK] IN=eth0 OUT= MAC=20:89:84:3b:68:fc:00:13:33:a7:c6:98:08:00 SRC=23.67.255.201 DST=192.168.1.27 LEN=52 TOS=0x00 PREC=0x00 TTL=61 ID=1874 DF PROTO=TCP SPT=80 DPT=40660 WINDOW=587 RES=0x00 ACK FIN URGP=0 
Jul  9 20:51:36 wilf-G570 kernel: [ 2192.888838] [UFW BLOCK] IN=eth0 OUT= MAC=20:89:84:3b:68:fc:00:13:33:a7:c6:98:08:00 SRC=103.31.7.34 DST=192.168.1.27 LEN=40 TOS=0x00 PREC=0x00 TTL=61 ID=20864 DF PROTO=TCP SPT=80 DPT=34403 WINDOW=30 RES=0x00 ACK FIN URGP=0 
Jul  9 20:51:37 wilf-G570 kernel: [ 2193.369941] [UFW BLOCK] IN=eth0 OUT= MAC=20:89:84:3b:68:fc:00:13:33:a7:c6:98:08:00 SRC=103.31.7.34 DST=192.168.1.27 LEN=40 TOS=0x00 PREC=0x00 TTL=61 ID=20865 DF PROTO=TCP SPT=80 DPT=34403 WINDOW=30 RES=0x00 ACK FIN URGP=0 
Jul  9 20:51:38 wilf-G570 kernel: [ 2194.330974] [UFW BLOCK] IN=eth0 OUT= MAC=20:89:84:3b:68:fc:00:13:33:a7:c6:98:08:00 SRC=103.31.7.34 DST=192.168.1.27 LEN=40 TOS=0x00 PREC=0x00 TTL=61 ID=20866 DF PROTO=TCP SPT=80 DPT=34403 WINDOW=30 RES=0x00 ACK FIN URGP=0 
Jul  9 20:51:40 wilf-G570 kernel: [ 2196.252933] [UFW BLOCK] IN=eth0 OUT= MAC=20:89:84:3b:68:fc:00:13:33:a7:c6:98:08:00 SRC=103.31.7.34 DST=192.168.1.27 LEN=40 TOS=0x00 PREC=0x00 TTL=61 ID=20867 DF PROTO=TCP SPT=80 DPT=34403 WINDOW=30 RES=0x00 ACK FIN URGP=0 
Jul  9 20:51:42 wilf-G570 kernel: [ 2198.792958] [UFW BLOCK] IN=eth0 OUT= MAC=20:89:84:3b:68:fc:00:13:33:a7:c6:98:08:00 SRC=104.16.16.44 DST=192.168.1.27 LEN=40 TOS=0x00 PREC=0x00 TTL=61 ID=44069 DF PROTO=TCP SPT=80 DPT=55730 WINDOW=135 RES=0x00 ACK FIN URGP=0 
Jul  9 20:51:42 wilf-G570 kernel: [ 2199.022927] [UFW BLOCK] IN=eth0 OUT= MAC=20:89:84:3b:68:fc:00:13:33:a7:c6:98:08:00 SRC=104.16.16.44 DST=192.168.1.27 LEN=40 TOS=0x00 PREC=0x00 TTL=61 ID=44070 DF PROTO=TCP SPT=80 DPT=55730 WINDOW=135 RES=0x00 ACK FIN URGP=0 
Jul  9 20:51:43 wilf-G570 kernel: [ 2199.483383] [UFW BLOCK] IN=eth0 OUT= MAC=20:89:84:3b:68:fc:00:13:33:a7:c6:98:08:00 SRC=104.16.16.44 DST=192.168.1.27 LEN=40 TOS=0x00 PREC=0x00 TTL=61 ID=44071 DF PROTO=TCP SPT=80 DPT=55730 WINDOW=135 RES=0x00 ACK FIN URGP=0 
Jul  9 20:51:44 wilf-G570 kernel: [ 2200.107845] [UFW BLOCK] IN=eth0 OUT= MAC=20:89:84:3b:68:fc:00:13:33:a7:c6:98:08:00 SRC=103.31.7.34 DST=192.168.1.27 LEN=40 TOS=0x00 PREC=0x00 TTL=61 ID=20868 DF PROTO=TCP SPT=80 DPT=34403 WINDOW=30 RES=0x00 ACK FIN URGP=0 
Jul  9 20:51:44 wilf-G570 kernel: [ 2200.574803] [UFW BLOCK] IN=eth0 OUT= MAC=20:89:84:3b:68:fc:00:13:33:a7:c6:98:08:00 SRC=104.16.16.44 DST=192.168.1.27 LEN=40 TOS=0x00 PREC=0x00 TTL=61 ID=44072 DF PROTO=TCP SPT=80 DPT=55730 WINDOW=135 RES=0x00 ACK FIN URGP=0 
Jul  9 20:51:46 wilf-G570 kernel: [ 2202.246441] [UFW BLOCK] IN=eth0 OUT= MAC=20:89:84:3b:68:fc:00:13:33:a7:c6:98:08:00 SRC=104.16.16.44 DST=192.168.1.27 LEN=40 TOS=0x00 PREC=0x00 TTL=61 ID=44073 DF PROTO=TCP SPT=80 DPT=55730 WINDOW=135 RES=0x00 ACK FIN URGP=0 
Jul  9 20:52:20 wilf-G570 kernel: [ 2236.144976] [UFW BLOCK] IN=eth0 OUT= MAC=20:89:84:3b:68:fc:00:13:33:a7:c6:98:08:00 SRC=190.93.246.58 DST=192.168.1.27 LEN=40 TOS=0x00 PREC=0x00 TTL=61 ID=56817 DF PROTO=TCP SPT=80 DPT=50317 WINDOW=30 RES=0x00 ACK FIN URGP=0
```

The router I think has just port 80 open (can't configure it at this point) - and I don't think it forwards ports to this or any other addresses. I should also add this is a home address with no domain name associated with it, with no servers with public websites.

Comment: do you include Google Analytics on the site?

Comment: no - I haven't put the site on yet so it is still the default XHTML test page. I'm setting it up to test it on on a vareity of machines to fix faults before putting it on the main (online) server.

Comment: I notice that it's on port 443, I assume that you've set up a certificate or have you self-signed?

Comment: I haven't set up HTTPS or anything yet.... this was just after installing the HTTP apache server and the firewall and turning them both on. The thing I'm not sure about is whether it should be able to access the local network in the first place...

Comment: Then I'd look at the router/firewall. I'd assume that there is port forwarding or your external IP is already known to Google's spiders.

Comment: Certainly something has configured a route through your router/firewall to that .27 machine. 216.58.208.35 is a brand monitor so another robot. I suspect they are all robots. You can use fail2ban to block them if they bother you but @schroeder is right, the route is set on the router somewhere.